# clicking search bar doesn't promp keypad (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

I'm a Swift noob, so sorry for the easy question.

I think I haven't attached the correct events for my search bar as when I click in it, the keyboard doesn't appear.

In the storyboard, I'm pretty sure I have to set the outlet for the UISearchBar's delegate to be the View Controller. But from this screenshot, it looks like the delegate is simply to the `view`. [image: this screenshot]

Here's my viewController.swift file, can someone help spot the error?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  PhotoSearchExample
//
//  Created by Tim Peterson on 10/30/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Tim Peterson. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    //@IBOutlet weak var searchString: UISearchBar!

    let instagramClientID = "xxxx"

    func searchInstagramByHashtag(searchString: String) {
        for subview in self.scrollView.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let instagramURLString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + searchString + "/media/recent?client_id=" + instagramClientID

        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

       self.scrollView.alpha = 0.0

        let activityIndictorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
        activityIndictorView.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(activityIndictorView)
        activityIndictorView.startAnimating()

        manager.GET( instagramURLString,
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

                if let dataArray = responseObject.valueForKey("data") as? [AnyObject] {
                    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, CGFloat(320*dataArray.count))
                    for var i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++ {
                        let dataObject: AnyObject = dataArray[i]
                        if let imageURLString = dataObject.valueForKeyPath("images.standard_resolution.url") as? String {
                            println("image " + String(i) + " URL is " + imageURLString)



                            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(320*i), 320, 320))
                            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
                            imageView.setImageWithURL( NSURL(string: imageURLString))

                            activityIndictorView.stopAnimating()

                            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
                                self.scrollView.alpha = 1.0
                                }, completion: {
                                    (value: Bool) in
                                    println("Animation complete!")
                            })

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        })
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar!) {

        //println("search bar clicked!")

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        searchInstagramByHashtag(searchBar.text)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        searchInstagramByHashtag("clararockmore")
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track Tim - you seem to have somehow set up your View as the delegate of your searchbar rather than the View Controller. I would recommend:

1. Delete the connection in your Connections inspector.
2. Open your Document Outline in the Interface Builder(button at the bottom left of Interface Builder)
3. Now it's clearer what exactly you're dragging to - control drag from the searchbar directly to the ViewController, select delegate, and you should see it appear correctly in the Connections Inspector.

Comment: that's perfect, thanks! ok the search functionality now works, but the keypad never appears. Is `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()` in the right place?

Comment: How can the search functionality be working if you say the keypad never appears? Oh - you're probably in the simulator, typing the search in using your computer keyboard. If so, in the simulator menu, turn off 'Hardware', 'Keyboard', 'Connect Hardware Keyboard' - or just view it on your device!

Comment: Yes i was in the simulator. Thanks again for the answer!